# Customizing My app W10 Template from AppStudio

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, microsoft-appstudio

Customizing My app W10 Template from AppStudio

Hello everyone, I’m new to programming and I wanted to make a Windows App just for fun, so far it looks good, however. I have a problem (mostly because I don’t know what I’m doing).
But I want the RSS feed to open Edge instead of the feed view (second page after you click on a feed icon)
I found the config file for the rss feed ( I called it news) but I don’t know how to make it open a new window on edge .
The code is located at:

Sections\NewsConfig.cs

Update: This is the full original code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AppStudio.DataProviders;
using AppStudio.DataProviders.Core;
using AppStudio.DataProviders.Rss;
using AppStudio.Uwp.Actions;
using AppStudio.Uwp.Commands;
using AppStudio.Uwp.Navigation;
using MyWindows10App.Config;
using MyWindows10App.ViewModels;

namespace MyWindows10App.Sections
{
public class NewsConfig : SectionConfigBase<RssDataConfig, RssSchema>
{
    public override DataProviderBase<RssDataConfig, RssSchema> DataProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return new RssDataProvider();
        }
    }

    public override RssDataConfig Config
    {
        get
        {
            return new RssDataConfig
            {
                Url = new Uri("https://localhost:804514/feed")
            };
        }
    }

    public override NavigationInfo ListNavigationInfo
    {
        get 
        {
            return NavigationInfo.FromPage("NewsListPage");
        }
    }

    public override ListPageConfig<RssSchema> ListPage
    {
        get 
        {
            return new ListPageConfig<RssSchema>
            {
                Title = "News",

                LayoutBindings = (viewModel, item) =>
                {
                    viewModel.Title = item.Title.ToSafeString();
                    viewModel.SubTitle = item.Summary.ToSafeString();
                    viewModel.Description = item.Summary.ToSafeString();
                    viewModel.Image = item.ImageUrl.ToSafeString();
                },
                NavigationInfo = (item) =>
                {
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public override DetailPageConfig<RssSchema> DetailPage
    {
        get
        {
            var bindings = new List<Action<ItemViewModel, RssSchema>>();

            var actions = new List<ActionConfig<RssSchema>>
            {
            };

            return new DetailPageConfig<RssSchema>
            {
                Title = "News",
                LayoutBindings = bindings,
                Actions = actions
            };
        }
    }

    public override string PageTitle
    {
        get { return "News"; }
    }
}
}
```

Update 2: here is the XAML from the List page

```
<Page
x:Class="MyWindows10App.Views.NewsListPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:was_actions="using:AppStudio.Uwp.Actions"
xmlns:was_commands="using:AppStudio.Uwp.Commands"
xmlns:was_controls="using:AppStudio.Uwp.Controls"
xmlns:layouts="using:MyWindows10App.Layouts"
xmlns:list_layouts="using:MyWindows10App.Layouts.List"
xmlns:controls="using:MyWindows10App.Layouts.Controls"
xmlns:vm="using:MyWindows10App.ViewModels"
xmlns:triggers="using:MyWindows10App.Triggers"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=/Assets/Design/DesignData.json, Type=vm:DesignViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="{StaticResource AppBackground}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{StaticResource AppBarBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="48"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{Binding ViewModel.PageTitleMargin}" Text="{Binding ViewModel.PageTitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource AppBarForeground}" FontSize="21" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" MaxLines="1"/>
    <was_actions:ActionsCommandBar 
        x:Name="appBar"
        ActionsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Actions}" Style="{StaticResource WasCommandBarStyle}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource AppBarForeground}"
        IsVisible="{Binding ViewModel.HasActions}"
        Background="{StaticResource AppBarBackground}"
        Grid.Row="{Binding ViewModel.AppBarRow}"
        Grid.Column="{Binding ViewModel.AppBarColumn}"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding ViewModel.AppBarColumnSpan}">
    </was_actions:ActionsCommandBar>
    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="3" Margin="0,6,0,6" IsIndeterminate="True" Foreground="{StaticResource PageTitleForeground}" Visibility="{Binding ViewModel.IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
    <was_controls:ErrorNotificationControl Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Uid="ListErrorNotificationControl" Grid.Row="2" ErrorVisibility="{Binding ViewModel.HasLoadDataErrors, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" ErrorColor="{StaticResource PageTitleForeground}" Margin="10,0,18,0"/>
    <list_layouts:ListBigHorizontalCardBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemClickCommand="{Binding ItemClickCommand}" OneRowModeEnabled="False" Margin="19,0,12,0" />
    <controls:DataUpdateInformationControl Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" LastUpdateDateTime="{Binding ViewModel.LastUpdated}" Color="{StaticResource PageTitleForeground}" Margin="8,4,8,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HasLocalData="{Binding ViewModel.HasLocalData}"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In UWP apps, While performing navigating you can use URI scheme or recommend any app to use that URI to open with.

You can use the [http URI scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228340.aspx#browser) to launch default web browser as follows

```
// The URI to launch
   var uriFeed = new Uri(@"http://www.myblogfeed.com");

   // Launch the URI
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriFeed);
```

when launching any URI, you can also pass in [LaucherOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228340.aspx) obect, where you can specify the preferredApplication for URI to launch it. Here is the example from a [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228340.aspx).

```
// Set the recommended app
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.PreferredApplicationPackageFamilyName = "Contoso.URIApp_8wknc82po1e";
options.PreferredApplicationDisplayName = "Contoso URI Ap";

// Launch the URI and pass in the recommended app 
// in case the user has no apps installed to handle the URI
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriContoso, options);
```

Comment: I think the first one will do the trick, however I don't want to pass the URL of the blog, I would like to use the URL of the post. how can I extract the post url ?

Comment: above doesn't seem to related to get the link, I think it should be already taking to you to the individual posts once you click on them?

Comment: How are you displaying the individual post? You should try to layout your logic around that

Comment: No it currently doesn't do anything, since I added the return null; before that it had this return NavigationInfo.FromPage("NewsDetailPage", true); but that only sent to the detail page.

Comment: umm I don't know how its displaying the posts, again I'm using the app studio sample called my app w10 from here http://appstudio.windows.com/projects/create